# Understanding the output of PrintRelocations in Hotspot

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

I am trying to understand how a method is stored in CodeBuffer (divided into three different sections) while it is getting compiled in HotSpot VM. I have printed relocation information however I don't fully understand it. This is my output:

```
   3918    1       1       Demo::workload (2 bytes)

// Relocation information in 3 sections of CodeBuffer

CodeBuffer:
  consts.code = 0x00007fffe11f27a0 : 0x00007fffe11f27a0 : 0x00007fffe11ff470 (0 of 52432)
  consts.locs = 0x00007fffac008910 : 0x00007fffac008910 : 0x00007fffac008918 (0 of 4) point=0
         @0x00007fffac008910: 

   insts.code = 0x00007fffe11727a0 : 0x00007fffe11727f2 : 0x00007fffe11f2320 (82 of 523136)
   insts.locs = 0x00007fffac0087b0 : 0x00007fffac0087b4 : 0x00007fffac008904 (2 of 170) point=77
         @0x00007fffac0087b0: b416
relocInfo@0x00007fffac0087b0 [type=11(poll_return) addr=0x00007fffe11727b6 offset=22 format=1]
         @0x00007fffac0087b2: 6437
relocInfo@0x00007fffac0087b2 [type=6(runtime_call) addr=0x00007fffe11727ed offset=55 format=1] | [destination=0x00007fffe116f1e0]
         @0x00007fffac0087b4: 


   stubs.code = 0x00007fffe11f2340 : 0x00007fffe11f23f5 : 0x00007fffe11f2780 (181 of 1088)
   stubs.locs = 0x00007fffb4009f90 : 0x00007fffb4009faa : 0x00007fffb4009fcc (13 of 30) point=176
         @0x00007fffb4009f90: 6428
relocInfo@0x00007fffb4009f90 [type=6(runtime_call) addr=0x00007fffe11f2368 offset=40 format=1] | [destination=0x00007fffe12037e0]
         @0x00007fffb4009f92: f803f6ad80097fff705b
relocInfo@0x00007fffb4009f9a [type=7(external_word) addr=0x00007fffe11f23c3 offset=91 data={f6ad80097fff}] | [target=0x00007ffff6ad8009]
         @0x00007fffb4009f9c: f060800a
relocInfo@0x00007fffb4009f9e [type=8(internal_word) addr=0x00007fffe11f23cd offset=10 data=96] | [target=0x00007fffe11f236d]
         @0x00007fffb4009fa0: 6411
relocInfo@0x00007fffb4009fa0 [type=6(runtime_call) addr=0x00007fffe11f23de offset=17 format=1] | [destination=0x00007ffff676dc98]
         @0x00007fffb4009fa2: f801fd729006
relocInfo@0x00007fffb4009fa6 [type=9(section_word) addr=0x00007fffe11f23e4 offset=6 data=-654] | [target=0x00007fffe11f23e4]
         @0x00007fffb4009fa8: 640c
relocInfo@0x00007fffb4009fa8 [type=6(runtime_call) addr=0x00007fffe11f23f0 offset=12 format=1] | [destination=0x00007fffe110f2e0]
         @0x00007fffb4009faa:
```

So these addresses after `@` are addresses of each relocation entry. But what does the 4 digit hex specify after `:`? And what is all the info after it?

Comment: it would be very helpful if you would show how you obtained this output

Comment: I am printing relocation information at the end of emit_code_body function in C1_Compilation.cpp using code()->print() and code()->decode_all()

Comment: I found some detailed comments in RelocInfo so I think it is making some sense now. Would still be great to hear if you have anything to add

Comment: it _seems_ you are using a debug jvm build, right?

Comment: yes yes I am using slowdebug build of Graal-JVMCI-8

Comment: that is the kind of info you include in the question... Its kind of hard to understand what you are doing without having a strong background... And btw, those comments you found are the best source of truth. These things can change from release to release and their are not documented

Comment: Yes I understand. And apologies for not including these details in the question. I will edit the question and write answer as well using those comments. Thank you

Comment: no need to apologize, your questions are great. the downside is that you will have a very limited audience to get answers, this is by far not something every average java developers looks at...

Comment: I understand I might not get much response but SO seems like the only option. Do you happen to know any community where JDK developers are active?

Comment: there are plenty of jdk devs (or previous jdk developer on this website), actually this is the best place to try to get answers

Comment: will continue to post questions here then =)